# golang: unable to use or download Parser from go/parser

Tags: go, package

I am going through "The Go Programming Language" book, chapter 7 page 200 states:
"we dont have space to show the Parse function here, but you'll find it if you download the package using go get"

reading, I beleive I need to download it with this: `go get github.com/golang/go/parser`
the function I need is in:`https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/go/parser`
but it returns

```
go get: module github.com/golang/go@upgrade found (v0.0.0-20210522005117-cca23a73733f), but does not contain package github.com/golang/go/parser
```

adding it into my imports, also doesnt work(isnt it part of the standard library?), I assume I am doing something silly here,
my gopath is set ok, I have used go get for other packages before.
I have tried to just download the parser.go file and use that but vim-go/gofmt just removes the import.
sorry for the stupid question but, I hate not seeing the example work and I am surely not understanding something here..

edit: in the end I just used the parser.go file from:
`https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/master/ch7/eval/parse.go`
although I would prefer to know what I am not understanding.

I am wondering if the book is referencing the function:

`func ParseExpr(x string) (ast.Expr, error)`
maybe the name has changed over time.

Comment: I wonder why when I tried to import it with ```import "go/parser"```, saving the file it was just removed, maybe it was how I am calling the Parser. thanks for the reply

Comment: It's already present in the standard library. No need to go get. GOPL book is old now and some of the stuff might not be correct. Just do an "import" and start writing your program. Every `go/*` package is already present.

Comment: I did wonder if it was just outdated, cheers

Comment: That makes sense, just had to call it with eval.Parse() appreciate the answer.